# "5 of a kind" hand in Poker Game

Tags: hand

According to [the Wikipedia on List of poker hands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands), the highest rank is "Five of a kind" and there is a Joker on it. It also wins against "Straight flush" and below.

A⋄ A♣ A♥ A♠ + Joker

This is the first I see that hand because I only play Texas Hold'em Poker.

So can anybody give some information on that? Is there any real game play on that type in the casino?

Comment: It really messes with odds.  If it can be any card it even changes the order of the hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you may be able to find live poker games in some casinos which feature a mix of games including some where wildcards are used such that a 5 of a kind hand may be possible - however this is in my experience extremely rare and you are much more likely to run into games with this feature in a home game.

When it comes to table games on the main casino floor, there are some games which incorporate wildcards/jokers and therefore feature the 5 of a kind hand - [Pai Gow Poker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pai_gow_poker) for example includes a joker which can be substituted for an Ace or to make any 5 card hand (like a straight or flush), so it is possible to make five Aces in this game.

Comment: ya Thnx for the reply But in this game the `Joker` part work as `bug` in that of Game.

Comment: Yes, in Pai Gow Poker, the joker is used as a Bug, which is a form of wildcard as described. Are you just asking for examples of games where the Joker is used as a pure wildcard?

Comment: Don't forget the old standby, 5 card draw. That was occasionally dealt with a joker used as a bug as well. I'm not sure if it was used as a true wild card, however, other than in home games.

Comment: @HerbWolfe fair point, although I've not seen a 5 card draw game "in the wild" for decades, except in home games.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently it's called Mexican poker 5 card draw with a joker. It is offered at Commerce casino in L.A.